# C# Make a List to hold any derived children of a base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

So I wish to setup an abstract base class to derive children classes from.  All the work will take place on the children, but I wanted the children to be able to reference each other.

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> : SomeOtherClass {

    public List<BaseClass> listOfChildren;

    protected T thisChild;

    public void DoMoreStuff(){
        Debug.Log("Doing more stuff");
    }

    protected virtual void DoSomething(int i){
        listOfChildren[i].DoMoreStuff();
    }
}

public class FirstChildClass : BaseClass<FirstChildClass> {

    FirstChildClass<T>(){
        thisChild = this;
    }

    public void FirstClassStuff(){
        Debug.Log("first class stuff");
    }

}
public class SecondChildClass : BaseClass<SecondChildClass> {

    public void SecondClassStuff(){
        Debug.Log("second class stuff");
    }
}
```

How would I make a generic List to accept any child class?

Will I need to typecast listOfChildren with T to use DoMoreStuff()?

On its own, is there anything else inherently wrong with this setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you overcompicate the solution. If you don't want to store any data in each node - try to solve this problem then without the generics. I will give you a naive straight-forward implementation of desired behavior as a starting point.

```
public abstract class BaseClass  {

    private IList<BaseClass> children = new List<BaseClass>();

    public void AddChild(BaseClass child)
    {
        this.children.Add(child);
    }

    protected virtual void DoMoreStuff(){
        Debug.Write("Doing more stuff");
    }

    public void DoSomething(int i){
        children[i].DoMoreStuff();
    }
}

public class FirstChildClass : BaseClass {

    protected override void DoMoreStuff(){
        Debug.Write("first class more stuff");
    }

}

public class SecondChildClass : BaseClass {

    protected override void DoMoreStuff(){
        Debug.Write("second class more stuff");
    }
}
```

now you can

```
var root = new FirstChildClass();

root.AddChild(new FirstChildClass());
root.AddChild(new SecondChildClass());
root.AddChild(new FirstChildClass());

root.DoSomething(1); //will print second class more stuff
root.DoSomething(0); //will print first class more stuff
```

Comment: to take it further, could I easily make each child class a Singleton?

Comment: @user1297102 do you really need that?

Comment: it would be useful in certain circumstances, is it something that would be difficult? I was thinking I could put a
'protected static T instance' (but this would need BaseClass<T> rite?) in the base, not sure how a constructor would be setup to if(!instance)instance=this;else"already exists" against that.

Comment: statics and inheritance don't mix

Answer (score 3):

You need to separate between child **classes** and child **data**.  A child class simply inherits from its parent, to provide a more detailed structure to the data (such as `Animal` and `Dog`).  A child data, on the other hand, means that whatever the data *represents* is related to each other (such as `Receipt` and `ReceiptLineItem`).

Normally, the two don't overlap.  The `Receipt` class looks nothing like the `ReceiptLineItem` class, and the `Receipt` and a `ExternalPurchaseOrder` have nothing to do with each other, even though they both inherit their structure from `Purchase`.  When they do overlap, you have a tree structure.  A `Product` may be composed of more `Product`s, which each may be composed of yet more `Product`s.

---

Here's how I'd rewrite your code, assuming you're looking for the first type of inheritance (class structure):

```
public abstract class BaseClass : SomeOtherClass {

    public static List<BaseClass> listOfChildren = new List<BaseClass>();

    public void DoMoreStuff(){
        Debug.Log("Doing more stuff");
    }

    protected virtual void DoSomething(int i){
        listOfChildren[i].DoMoreStuff();
    }
}

public class FirstChildClass : BaseClass {

    FirstChildClass(){
       // Set some things unique to this class
    }

    public void FirstClassStuff(){
        Debug.Log("first class stuff");
    }

}
public class SecondChildClass : BaseClass<SecondChildClass> {

    public void SecondClassStuff(){
        Debug.Log("second class stuff");
    }
}
```

You could then access the master list as `BaseClass.listOfChildren`.  If you want all children to automatically register themselves, you can add that to the `BaseClass` constructor:

```
protected BaseClass()
{
   listOfChildren.Add(this);
}
```

Comment: to take it further, could I easily make each child class a Singleton?

Comment: And just out of technical curiosity, if I wanted to implement my less-than-stellar design, how would it be possible to make that List work? (if in the future I need to mix generics and classes)

Comment: @user1297102 - I'm not quite sure what you mean.  If you're asking how you can have a `List<BaseClass>`, then you actually need a `BaseClass` class (or interface), which `BaseClass<T>` can inherit from (or implement).  The existence of `BaseClass<T>` doesn't imply the existence of a non-generic form, and each different `T` produces a different class, so there's no way to "group" them if you only have the generic type.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, but wasn't sure if I just didn't think of something.